# Referencing foreign key in CodeIgniter Active Record and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm writing a basic intranet application that displays a company's outstanding orders from an orders database, which should cross-reference a customer database to display both the outstanding order by order and customer id (from order_db) and the customer's name (from customer_db).

trouble is, i'm quite new to php, mysql and codeigniter, and while i've managed to display all the active orders in a table format, i can't seem to find much help on how to reference foreign keys using the active record helper in codeigniter.  i'm hoping someone can help me.

here is my model function:

```
    function get_orders_and_customers()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('customer_db');
        $this->db->join('order_db', 'order_db.cust_id = customer_db.cust_id');

        $query = $this->db->get('customer_db');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

i call both the model for the order_db and the one above in my site controller, and then just use a foreach in the view to return each row's column data.  unfortunately, codeigniter does not seem to recognise name; ?> from the customer_db (the order_db display works perfectly).

i realise that i may have this completely backward, so any help would be appreciated.  thanks

Comment: I didn't understand your question, but if you're using $this->db->from(table), you don't need to specify the table in the get... just like this $this->db->get();

Comment: i'm trying to display the customer's name (stored in customer_db) in the order list by matching the common key cust_id (found in both order_db and customer_db).  i'm not sure how to do this, since codeigniter does not return the customer name value through my current model

Answer (score 0):

If you use $this->db->last_query(); does it show the name in the selection for the query? Sorry, would have used comments for this but rep needs to be higher for that first :)

Other than that, you can also make use of

```
<?php
foreach($result as $r) {
  var_dump($r);
}
?>
```

just to see what the full record is that is returned for each. This should help in identifying if you are potentially accessing the field incorrectly or not

Comment: i managed to solve it in the view by just using an if statement to match the two order_ids from two separate queries.  thanks for the response